# How to print only different lines of two text files in GREP?

Tags: grep

How to print only different lines of two text files in GREP?
I need to print just lines which aren't in second text file....

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you want `diff` instead of `grep`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `-F -f <file>`:

```
grep -Fvf file2 file1
```

This tells you the lines of `file1` which do *not* (`-v`) appear in `file2`.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to use grep?

Sounds like you need *diff*

```
$ cat file1
a
b
c

$ cat file2
b
```

You can use diff to compare them:

```
$ diff file1 file2
1d0
< a
3d1
< c
```

Use -y option to generate better visaul comparison:

```
$ diff -y file1 file2
a                                                             <
b                                                             b
c                                                             <
```